# PHP IRC BOT wont connect

Tags: php, sockets, bots, irc

2 years ago it worked and now firing off with some annyoing errors what I cannot find the answer to it why it doesnst work:

```
$this->BotSocket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
    if (!$this->BotSocket) {
        die('Socket error1 : '.socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    }
    /**
     * Bind the socket to make it irc'able 
     */

    if(!socket_bind($this->BotSocket, $this->BotConfig['hostname'])) { 
        die('Socket error2 : '.socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    }


    if(!socket_connect($this->BotSocket, $this->BotConfig['server'], $this->BotConfig['port'])) { 
        die('Socket error3 : '.socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    }
```

and the connection strings:

```
        $this->BotConfig = array(

        /**
         * Bot configuration for information
         */

        'nickname' => 'Muts',
        'realname' => 'Vii personal funbot',
        'ident'    => 'Muts',

        /**
         * Bot server configration
         */

        'hostname' => 0,
        'server'   => 'OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net',
        'port'     => 6667,
```

(there is more in the array it is closed correcty)
and the error I get:

> Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [110]: Connection timed out in /home/patrick/domains/xxxx/public_html/muts/bot.php on line 225
>   Socket error3 : Connection timed out

anybody can help me out with this?

also notable:
- Working with same connection settings with telnet
- Working with same connection settings with mIRC
- It's running of an webserver (external not local computer)

Result for host:OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net is an alias for ogn2.ogamenet.net. ogn2.ogamenet.net has address 79.110.87.154 - traceroute: traceroute to 79.110.87.154 (79.110.87.154), 30 hops max, 40 byte packet

Comment: connection timed out = you can't reach the server, or it's ignoring you. e.g. you've been firewalled off.

Comment: Did you test this against a local IRC server to make sure it is in fact your code and not something external to your program?

Comment: server is active and the port is working cause when I connect with mirc with the same settings it works, same for telnet so that aint the problem

Answer (score 1):

That error is pointing to something external, other than your code - especially if it worked prior.

Check your firewall settings and socket port(s), and that the server that you are connecting to is active.

Comment: server is active and the port is working cause when I connect with mirc with the same settings it works, same for telnet so that aint the problem

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the top of your PHP file to get more detailed error messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

---

Give these a try if you have SSH access:

**DNS problem?**

```
host OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net
```

**Routing problem?**

```
traceroute 79.110.87.154
```

**Attempt a full TCP handshake**

```
telnet OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net 6667
```

Comment: with the extra error_reporting nothing else shows up, and I have no ssh access so I cannot test that ..

Comment: Not even with `system("host OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net")` etc from a php script?

Comment: Result for host:OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net is an alias for ogn2.ogamenet.net. ogn2.ogamenet.net has address 79.110.87.154 - traceroute: traceroute to 79.110.87.154 (79.110.87.154), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets

Comment: ok, try telnet `system("(sleep 2 ; echo QUIT) | telnet OGN2.OnlineGamesNet.net 6667")`

Comment: "Trying 79.110.87.154... " but nothing happens... further more

Comment: Then i´ll guess that is part of your problem, telnet hangs until a timeout trying to connect. If it would have worked you should have seen some IRC protocol commands. Maybe your hosting provider has a firewall preventing outwards connections?

Comment: result:

HTTP/1.0 302 Found Location: http://www.google.nl/ Cache-Control: private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=798b3e9778213c92:FF=0:TM=1350214830:LM=1350214830:S=4cDwmNyziRtuaMeT; expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 11:40:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com Set-Cookie: NID=64=SuVcptfdLMoXWzRyOH1dc9b2MN3qWMMsMUOm4XF6d9pVb8SfTVPQh5g8_FaMnCrtwDJXM9y87cCJsM2QpEjcvLYzDqA3-K9azkbsfY8dGYVmovZsAy8wUTTI-YqQIJms; expires=Mon, 15-Apr-2013 11:40:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?.....

Comment: Ok so i guess that TCP connections work on port 80 but port 6667 seems to be filtered somehow? Maybe try to use some other port (or server) http://www.onlinegamesnet.net/servers.php unfortunately non of them seem to listen on port 80 but i guess your best chance is port 8080

Comment: hmm still get the same error on port 8080 :(, I think there is no way arround is there?

Comment: Not that i could think of :( more then asking your hosting provider for help or try to find a IRC server using port 80